# How to nest a join into a complicated Select sum(case, group by statement

Tags: sql, case

I am trying to generate a report, and so far have one completed that gives me how many orders, for each day, are in status 1-9.

TableA structure looks like this:

```
Sales Order | Order Status | Order Date
123456789 | 1 | 2017-02-22 00:00:00.000
123456790 | 0 | 2017-02-21 00:00:00.000
```

TableB structure looks like this:

```
Sales Order | Price
123456789 | 123.00
123456789 | 42.00
123456790 | 56.00
123456790 | 28.00
```

This code:

```
SELECT
    MAX(year([OrderDate])) as Yr,
    MAX(MONTH([OrderDate])) as M,
    Day([OrderDate]) as Day, 
    sum(case when [OrderStatus]='0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'STATUS"0"',
    sum(case when [OrderStatus]='1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'STATUS"1"',
    sum(case when [OrderStatus]='2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'STATUS"2"',
    sum(case when [OrderStatus]='4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'STATUS"4"',
    sum(case when [OrderStatus]='8' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'STATUS"8"',
    sum(case when [OrderStatus]='9' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'STATUS"9"',
    sum(case when [OrderStatus]='S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'STATUS"S"',
    sum(case when [OrderStatus]='*' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'STATUS"*"',
    sum(case when [OrderStatus]='/' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'STATUS"/"'
FROM 
    SorMaster  
WHERE 
    YEAR([OrderDate]) = YEAR(GETDATE())
GROUP BY
    DATENAME(month, DateAdd(month, Month([OrderDate]) - 1, Cast('2008-01-01' AS Datetime))), Day([OrderDate]) 
ORDER BY
    Yr DESC, M DESC, Day DESC
```

Returns this:

```
Yr | M | Day | STATUS"0" | STATUS"1" | STATUS"2" | STATUS"4" | STATUS"8" | STATUS"9" | STATUS"S" | STATUS"*" | STATUS"/"
2017    2   22  0   2   0   1   0   0   5   0   0
2017    2   21  0   0   0   7   0   0   0   0   0
```

This is PERFECT for my first report.

Now, comes the trouble.  My Problem is that I need to nest-query Table B, so that instead of returning a count(orders), I need the sum(orders) those totals for each order are in Table B.

Using the above example, the query would need to return something like this:

```
Yr | M | Day | STATUS"0" | STATUS"1" | STATUS"2" | STATUS"4" | STATUS"8" | STATUS"9" | STATUS"S" | STATUS"*" | STATUS"/"
2017    2   22  0   165 0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2017    2   21  84  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Any pointers?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? It often does make a difference whether you're using MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server or IBM DB2 - or something else even. Please add a relevant tag to your question!

Answer (score 1):

Just join to `TableB`:

```
SELECT MAX(year([t1.OrderDate])) AS Yr,
       MAX(MONTH([t2.OrderDate])) AS M,
       DAY([t1.OrderDate]) AS Day, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN [OrderStatus] = '0' THEN t2.Price ELSE 0 END) AS 'STATUS"0"',
       SUM(CASE WHEN [OrderStatus] = '1' THEN t2.Price ELSE 0 END) AS 'STATUS"1"',
       SUM(CASE WHEN [OrderStatus] = '2' THEN t2.Price ELSE 0 END) AS 'STATUS"2"',
       SUM(CASE WHEN [OrderStatus] = '4' THEN t2.Price ELSE 0 END) AS 'STATUS"4"',
       SUM(CASE WHEN [OrderStatus] = '8' THEN t2.Price ELSE 0 END) AS 'STATUS"8"',
       SUM(CASE WHEN [OrderStatus] = '9' THEN t2.Price ELSE 0 END) AS 'STATUS"9"',
       SUM(CASE WHEN [OrderStatus] = 'S' THEN t2.Price ELSE 0 END) AS 'STATUS"S"',
       SUM(CASE WHEN [OrderStatus] = '*' THEN t2.Price ELSE 0 END) AS 'STATUS"*"',
       SUM(CASE WHEN [OrderStatus] = '/' THEN t2.Price ELSE 0 END) AS 'STATUS"/"'
FROM SorMaster t1
LEFT JOIN TableB t2
    ON t1.[Sales Order] = t2.[Sales Order]  
WHERE YEAR([OrderDate]) = YEAR(GETDATE())
GROUP BY DATENAME(month,DateAdd(month,Month([OrderDate])-1,Cast('2008-01-01' AS Datetime))),
         DAY([OrderDate]) 
ORDER BY Yr DESC, M DEACLLSC, Day DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not too difficult, just a matter of LEFT JOINing in table B and then summing the prices in that.  There's a couple of small tricks here.  You want to LEFT JOIN to ensure that rows in table A always show up, even if there are no corresponding rows in table B.  Secondly, in your `SUM()` statement, you'll need to add a `COALESCE(...,0.00)` to ensure you're summing decimals and no `NULL` values creep in from the `LEFT JOIN`.  Oddly in databases, `NULL + {anything} = NULL`.

For the below query, you'll need to change the name of `TableB` to whatever the table name is, and the `JOIN` predicate will need to have the column names named accurately, and delimited correctly if they contain spaces.  For example, in MSSQL the delimiters are `[` and `]`, e.g. `MyTable.[My Column With Spaces]`

```
SELECT  
    MAX(YEAR([OrderDate])) as Yr,
    MAX(MONTH([OrderDate])) as M,
    DAY([OrderDate]) as Day, 
    sum(case when [OrderStatus]='0' THEN COALESCE(TableB.Price, 0.00) ELSE 0.00 END) AS 'STATUS"0"',
    sum(case when [OrderStatus]='1' THEN COALESCE(TableB.Price, 0.00) ELSE 0.00 END) AS 'STATUS"1"',
    sum(case when [OrderStatus]='2' THEN COALESCE(TableB.Price, 0.00) ELSE 0.00 END) AS 'STATUS"2"',
    sum(case when [OrderStatus]='4' THEN COALESCE(TableB.Price, 0.00) ELSE 0.00 END) AS 'STATUS"4"',
    sum(case when [OrderStatus]='8' THEN COALESCE(TableB.Price, 0.00) ELSE 0.00 END) AS 'STATUS"8"',
    sum(case when [OrderStatus]='9' THEN COALESCE(TableB.Price, 0.00) ELSE 0.00 END) AS 'STATUS"9"',
    sum(case when [OrderStatus]='S' THEN COALESCE(TableB.Price, 0.00) ELSE 0.00 END) AS 'STATUS"S"',
    sum(case when [OrderStatus]='*' THEN COALESCE(TableB.Price, 0.00) ELSE 0.00 END) AS 'STATUS"*"',
    sum(case when [OrderStatus]='/' THEN COALESCE(TableB.Price, 0.00) ELSE 0.00 END) AS 'STATUS"/"'
FROM  SorMaster
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB
    ON TableB.SalesOrder = SorMaster.SalesOrder
WHERE  YEAR([OrderDate]) = YEAR(GETDATE())
GROUP BY 
    DATENAME(month,DateAdd(month,Month([OrderDate])-1,Cast('2008-01-01' AS Datetime))),
    DAY([OrderDate]) 
ORDER BY
    Yr DESC,
    M DESC,
    Day DESC
```

Comment: this also worked!  Thanks for the detailed explanation also

Answer (score 0):

By (left) joining tableB and replacing your 'count' ones by tableB.price you should get the sum of all positions of orders with the according status.